# How Mapbox Raster Tiles API and Mapbox Static Tiles API differs in developer implementation?

Tags: mapbox

In one of my web-based project, I am considering to use Mapbox Tiles API , It provides two types of Tiles APIs :

**Raster Tiles API**

The Mapbox Raster Tiles API serves raster tiles. Each API request results in a single tile from a raster tileset like Mapbox Satellite or another Mapbox-hosted raster tileset.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/raster-tiles-api/

**Static Tiles API**

The Mapbox Static Tiles API serves raster tiles generated from a Mapbox GL-based style.

https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/static-tiles-api/

**Q**: How should I understand the difference between the two at a developer/implementation level?

ignore my edit

Answer (score 1):

Q1 Raster tiles API: "Upload raster data, get back raster tiles".
Static tiles API: "Upload vector data, get back raster tiles".

Q2: Hopefully Q1 answers this.

Q3: I don't understand.